# SQL: How to find minimum in minimum set with joins efficiently

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by

I want to find the oldest person in smallest class present in a school

I have a table like this

```
School  Class    DOB         Stu_ID 

1       1      2000-10-05     S007  
1       1      2001-08-03     S006
1       2      2000-10-05     S005      
1       2      2001-08-03     S004
2       3      2000-10-05     S003
2       4      2001-08-03     S002
2       4      2000-10-05     S001
2       5      2001-08-03     S009
```

I need to get the result table as

```
School  Class    DOB         Stu_ID 

1       1      2000-08-03     S006  
2       3      2000-10-05     S003
```

i.e., Oldest person in the smallest class in each school.

Comment: Nice. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What engine and version?

Comment: Your expected output is WRONG. `Stu_ID` and `DOB` doesn't match on both rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    School, Class, DOB, Stu_ID
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        School, Class, DOB, Stu_ID,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY School ORDER BY Class, DOB) AS rn
    FROM
        MyTable
    ) X
WHERE X.rn = 1
```

rn is reset per school (PARTITION BY) and counts from lowest class first then earliest DOB).

DENSE_RANK allows students to share birthdays

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ranking function:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT School, Class, DOB, Stu_ID,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY School ORDER BY Class ASC)
    FROM dbo.Schools
)
SELECT School, Class, DOB, Stu_ID
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6905/1/0)

- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [WITH common_table_expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use window functions to calculate intermediate variables:

```
select School, Class, DOB, Stu_ID 
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank(ClassCnt) over (partition by school) as ClassSizeRank
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by school, class) as ClassCnt,
                   row_number over (partition by school, class order by dob) as AgeSegnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where ageseqnum = 1 and ClassSizeRank = 1;
```

I would not recommend using joins for this type of query.  If this is for homework/class, you should specify that in the question.